# logging the outcome of netstat while using psexec for variable users

Tags: batch-file, logging, psexec, netstat

```
for /L %%h in (100, 1, 254) DO C:\systoys\PsExec.exe \\192.168.1.%%h -n 5 netstat -an | find "LISTEN"
```

With the above string in a batch file, psexec attempts to login to every user, and run a netstat and only return listen servers. How can I output the result to a log file? I am out of characters in cmd and need to be able to review all of the users

I have tried

```
for /L %%h in (100, 1, 254) DO C:\systoys\PsExec.exe \\192.168.1.%%h -n 5 netstat -an | find "LISTEN" >> \\server\logs\log.log
```

and of course the result is not going into the log, the log is created at the begenning of the batch though with a date stamp. I feel s though the >> is perhaps writing for, DO, or even find blankly to the file.

Comment: Does putting the command after `Do` in brackets help.

Comment: eliminating psexec and doing:

'code' C:\systoys\PsExec.exe \\192.168.1.223 -n 5 netstat -an | find "LISTEN" >> \\server\logs\log.log

does decent, but doesnt print which machine it is. I simply did that as a test.

I think you may be onto something with the DO, using brackets like 

'code'  for /L %%h in (100, 1, 254) DO [C:\systoys\PsExec.exe \\192.168.1.%%h -n 5 netstat -an | find "%port%" | echo >> \\server\logs\log.log

causes it to close unexpectedly.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problems with psexec in a for/parentheses, but with a call to a sub it worked somehow. The batch echoes a date time stamp with the IP.

```
@Echo off
Set Log=\\server\logs\log.log
:: Type NUL >%Log%
for /L %%h in (100, 1, 254) Do Call :Exec \\192.168.1.%%h
Echo %date% %time% Processing done ----------------------------->>%Log%
:: Notepad.exe %Log%
Goto :Eof

:Exec
Echo %date% %time% Processing %1 ----------------------------->>%Log%
PsExec.exe %1 -n 5 netstat -an | find "LISTEN">>%Log% 2>&1
```

Two commands are commented out at the moment:

1. `Type Nul >%Log%` which resets the log
2. `Notepad.exe %Log%` to view the log once the batch is finished